# Video.js wrong aspect ratio with flash player until full screen toggled

Tags: video.js

I'm having a problem with video.js where the video's aspect ratio is wrong (letterboxing on sides) in the video.js swf player until I toggle full screen mode. It loads with the incorrect aspect ratio, and when I go into full screen mode, it's still in the incorrect aspect ratio, but when I exit full screen mode, it goes to the correct aspect ratio. If I go back to full screen mode, it's the incorrect aspect ratio, but the correct aspect ratio remains out of full screen mode.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Confirmed. I have had the same problem.